# Building json path expression - presence of DOT in attribute name

Tags: json, jsonpath

We are working with a legacy system which gives json responses. We trying to test these json endpoints with jmeter. So, we are trying to use the json path extractor plugin for the purpose. But the structure of the json path is causing an issue in creating json path expressions.

The structure of the json which we are receiving from the server is as follows.

```
  {   
"ns9.Shopping": {
"transactionID": "XXXXXNEKIHJO7SRHN1",
"transactionStatus": "Success",
"ns9.shoppingResponseIDs":     {
    "ns9.owner": "1P",
    "ns9.responseId": "abcdefghijklmnop"
},
"ns9.offersGroup": {"ns9.thanksGiving":     [
            {
        "ns9.owner": "DL",
        "ns9.retailOffer":             [
                            {
                "ns9.offerId": "offer1DL",
                "ns9.price": 2639.08,
                "ns9.currencyCode": "USD",
                "ns9.taxTotal": 961.08,
                "ns9.taxCode": "USD",
               .........
```

The presence of . [DOT] in the attribute name is causing issues in my json path expression.

In short, can some one help in finding the "transactionID" from "ns9.Shopping"?

Comment: Read the JSONPath docs, and you will see that you can use the `["ns9.shopping"]` syntax, similar to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) within your HTTP Request element.

Put this regex:

```
"transactionID": "([a-zA-Z0-9]*)"
```

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: the question is "In short, can some one help in finding the "transactionID" from "ns9.Shopping"?". Rather than using JSONPathExtractor to get transactionID value, you will get difficulty. Because in JSONPathExtractor you need to use . [DOT] i.e. $.data[0].field1[0].data, while the response

Comment: While the response of the json will contains "ns9.Shopping".

Comment: if you use Regular Expression Extractor, the json will be threat as common text and you can find the "TransactionID" value easily.